# Is it possible to use my own vite version with svelte kit

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I'm running into this issue with vite+tailwind https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4150 And svelte-kit isn't using the patch that fixes it so I need to basically bring my own vite. Is this possible?

Comment: I found a solution.... Use WindiCSS! https://windicss.org/integrations/vite.html

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a different Vite version, or a specific Git commit, on the `package.json` file of your project. Eg: `"vite": "git://github.com/username/package.git#commit"`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Does this work even though vite it bundled in sveltekit? I figured this would only add vite as a dependancy but not update sveltekit's version of vite